# Python-check 3*3 matrix in a 9*9 matrix for duplicate, as in sudoku

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

[image: Detect duplicate in each 3*3 block in a 9*9 matrix]

My approach: use numpy.vsplit and hsplit to split the 9*9 into 9 3*3 blocks
and use .flat function to flatten each 3*3 block, then use set() to check if the list contains duplicate

```
import numpy as np
def validSolution(board):


    b=np.array(board)
    b=np.vsplit(b,3)
    for n,ar in enumerate(b):
        b[n]=np.hsplit(ar,3)

    for ar in b:
        for arr in ar:
            print(len(set(arr.flat))==len(arr.flat))

validSolution([[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
               [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
               [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
               [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
               [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
               [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
               [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
               [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
               [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]])
```

As I'm quite inexperienced in python and numpy, I would like to ask for a more efficient way to do this job.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: yes it did, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup : Let's say `a` is the `9x9` grid and `b` is the `3x3` sub-matrix (smaller grid) that you are searching for in `a`.

Steps :

- One way to solve it would be reshape `a` into `4D` : `a4D` of shape `(3,3,3,3)`, thus each window would be along the second and fourth axes.
- We need to extend `b` to `3D` so that the first axis is aligned with the second axis from `a4D` and the second one with the fourth one from `a4D`.
- Perform comparison, which would be efficient, courtesy NumPy broadcasting, giving us a `4D` boolean array. Look for all matches along those two dims and simply get the matching indices.

Hence, the implementation -

```
np.argwhere((a.reshape(3,3,3,3) == b[:,None]).all((1,3)))
```

Sample run -

```
In [190]: a
Out[190]: 
array([[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
       [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
       [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
       [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
       [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
       [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
       [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]])

In [196]: b = a[-3:,-6:-3] # (2,1) grid

In [197]: b
Out[197]: 
array([[5, 3, 7],
       [4, 1, 9],
       [2, 8, 6]])

In [198]: np.argwhere((a.reshape(3,3,3,3) == b[:,None]).all((1,3)))
Out[198]: array([[2, 1]])

In [199]: b = a[:3:,:3] # (0,0) grid

In [200]: b
Out[200]: 
array([[5, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 2],
       [1, 9, 8]])

In [201]: np.argwhere((a.reshape(3,3,3,3) == b[:,None]).all((1,3)))
Out[201]: array([[0, 0]])
```

If that looks messy for some reason and you prefer working with `built-ins`, we can use [`view_as_blocks`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) from `scikit-image`, to have a shape-agnostic solution -

```
In [206]: from skimage.util.shape import view_as_blocks

In [207]: np.argwhere((view_as_blocks(a, b.shape) == b).all((2,3)))
Out[207]: array([[0, 0]])
```

Note that these reshapes are all just `views`, so no extra memory space needed for them. Though the comparisons would lead to creating a boolean array of the same shape as `a`, but being a boolean array that would be much lighter (8 times lighter on Linux systems) than int/float arrays, so not too bad there on memory efficiency.